# angular.isDefined(obj) doesn't work if "obj" is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm used to typing the somewhat messy `typeof obj !== "undefined"` idiom. However, I noticed the `angular.isDefined(obj)` method.  The documentation says it will return false if the given object is not defined.  However, what it's actually doing (in Firefox, at least) is just failing, saying "obj is not defined".  Am I missing something?

Comment: what does it do in other browsers?

Comment: try putting this before you check if obj is defined: var obj = undefined. Alternatively you could probably check if window.obj was defined using angular.isDefined()

Comment: or even just `var obj;` before checking `isDefined()`

Comment: @smerny: If you want to test whether `obj` is defined in the same scope, then yes. If `obj` could be defined in a higher scope, then `var obj;` would shadow the other `obj`.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, this just shows how `isDefined()` works, typically it would be a var that you know exists and you are just checking if it got defined... like a method parameter: `function foo(bar) { if(angular.isDefined(bar)) { ... } ...`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874871/error-when-passing-undefined-variable-to-function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr;**: `angular.isDefined(obj)` is not a complete substitute for `typeof`.

---

> Am I missing something?

I don't think so. `typeof` is a special operator that doesn't throw an error if `obj` does not exist at all. However, passing a variable to a function will result in trying to read the value of the variable and hence throw an error if it does not exist. There is no way to prevent that.

AFAIK `typeof` is the only operator that doesn't throw if it encounters a reference error. On the other hand, if you have to test whether a variable exists or not, then your code is probably poorly designed (unless you have to test for existence of "features" (like third-party modules)).

Examples of the expected behavior:

```
var foo;
var bar = 42;

typeof foo !== 'undefined'; // false
typeof bar !== 'undefined'; // true
typeof baz !== 'undefined'; // false

isDefined(foo); // false
isDefined(bar); // true
isDefined(baz); // ReferenceError
```

Comment: As a side question does it make more sense to use plain javascript  "if" check instead of angular.isDefined as "if" check seems to be more safe in that it will safeguard against null values as well. I am not able to understand in which scenario angular.isDefined gives definite advantage over plain "if" check? Can you please touch uplon this

Answer (score 3):

Accessing a truly undefined variable in any way in Javascript, except `tyepof` throws an error. You can only use **Angular.isDefined** with **properties**. E.g, this would work fine:

```
Angular.isDefined(window.obj);
```

Because **obj** is an undefined propery of **window**.

Answer (score 0):

I try something like this:

```
try {
        if (angular.isDefined (obj.a.b)) {
            // do something with obj.a.b
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // handle cases if any of (obj, obj.a, obj.a.b) is not defined
    }
```

this way I dont get any exception, if any referenced property in the object hierarchy is not defined.